# How can I label days of month?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In HighCharts JS, how can I label the days of the month (ie label the blue bars) with the day of the month under each bar as shown in the following graph (**shown in the JSFiddle below**). At the moment, HighCharts skips labelling some days. My customer would prefer them to be labelled as consecutive/continuous numbers.

The JS Fiddle for HighCharts is here: http://jsfiddle.net/vecbtw7m/

**JavaScript code for HighCharts:**

```
$('#graphContainer2').highcharts({
    chart: { type: 'column' },
    title: { text: 'Monthly Page Views' },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: { text: 'Date' },
        min: new Date('2015/10/15').getTime(),
        max: new Date('2015/10/30').getTime(),
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: { text: 'Page Views' }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Page Views',
        data: [
           [Date.UTC(2015,9,15), 27], [Date.UTC(2015,9,17), 54],
           [Date.UTC(2015,9,20), 42], [Date.UTC(2015,9,24), 13]
        ]
     }]
});
```

**Desired result (in yellow)**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add label formatter function in xAxis :

```
xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
        title: { text: 'Date' },
        min: new Date('2015/10/15').getTime(),
        max: new Date('2015/10/30').getTime(),
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        labels:{
        formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d', this.value);
                }
}
```

}

Update [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azharamin/vecbtw7m/2/)

Comment: Thanks but that still omits every other day in my example. 14, 16, 18 etc. Is there no way to force it to output the number for every single day (there is enough room)?

Comment: For that you can add tickInterval in xAxis object. Updated my answer & fiddle, please have a look.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. If I add tickInterval to your fiddle, I get the same result.

Comment: For date you have to add this in xAxis "tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000"

Comment: Actually, this only seems to work if there are lots of data points. If there are just a few, then then this method doesn't work :(  See: http://jsfiddle.net/vecbtw7m/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) option for the x axis.

Ref:

> The interval of the tick marks in axis units. When null, the tick
>   interval is computed to approximately follow the tickPixelInterval on
>   linear and datetime axes. On categorized axes, a null tickInterval
>   will default to 1, one category. Note that datetime axes are based on
>   milliseconds, so for example an interval of one day is expressed as 24
>   * 3600 * 1000.
>
> On logarithmic axes, the tickInterval is based on powers, so a
>   tickInterval of 1 means one tick on each of 0.1, 1, 10, 100 etc. A
>   tickInterval of 2 means a tick of 0.1, 10, 1000 etc. A tickInterval of
>   0.2 puts a tick on 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 40 etc.
>
> If the tickInterval is too dense for labels to be drawn, Highcharts
>   may remove ticks.

Code:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    title: { text: 'Date' },
    min: new Date('2015/10/15').getTime(),
    max: new Date('2015/10/30').getTime(),
    tickInterval: 1
},
```

Result:

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jpnL65js/

### EDIT

Because of the note:

> If the tickInterval is too dense for labels to be drawn, Highcharts
>   may remove ticks.

you have to use another way, so use [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) function and force the ticks to display.

Ref:

> A callback function returning array defining where the ticks are laid
>   out on the axis. This overrides the default behaviour of
>   tickPixelInterval and tickInterval. The automatic tick positions are
>   accessible through this.tickPositions and can be modified by the
>   callback.

Code:

```
tickPositioner: function () {
    var result = [];
    for (i = 15; i < 31; i++)
    result.push(Date.UTC(2015, 9, i));

    result.info = {
        unitName: "day",
        higherRanks: {} 
    };

    return result;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezpo47ua/

Result:
[image]

Comment: That renders identically to my original fiddle when I run it?  Did you Save?  Are you sure tickInterval works with datetime graphs?

Comment: Not sure :) All I know is, If I load my fiddle, and yours, there is no difference at all. Can screenshot if you want?

Comment: Your result above even shows that it's not doing what I asked in my question.  Shows 14th and 16th, but not 15th - as such, doesn't solve my question.

Comment: @NickG new solution add, I hope is well for you

Comment: That worked when I had lots of datapoints, but if I only have a few, I get a "nonsense" graph where the columns span multiple days. See: http://jsfiddle.net/vecbtw7m/7/

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to a combination of two things:

- `tickInterval`
- `pointRange`

Setting both the point range and the tick interval to one day, the axis is aligned and formatted as you describe.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9cL3z64n/

Adding additional formatting to the labels can clean it all up, otherwise the labels get pretty sloppy.